# How to iterate an xml file and store it in map

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

How to iterate an file using rapidXml and store it in a map... Something like creating a dictionary using the contents of file. I have tried this but i can get only the first level of key-value pairs not the inner levels.

```
typedef map <string, string> MapType;
  MapType                 mProfiles;
        mXmlDocument.parse<parse_full>(&xml_copy[0]);

        for (xml_node<> *node = mXmlDocument.first_node();
             node; node = node->next_sibling())
        {
            mProfiles[node->name()] = node->value();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the value of the node, also examine the type.  If the type is `rapidxml:::node_element` or `rapidxml:::node_document` it may have children.

See the member function `rapidxml::print_node` in `rapidxml_print.hpp`.